# How to Replace Form Without Triggering the Change Event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to validate a `form` with an AJAX request to the server and then swap the `form` html in the web browser with the `form` html from the server because this would be an easy implementation in theory.  It is proving a nightmare though because the `change` event is triggered without the user interacting further after the first interaction which triggered the first change event.  Consequently an infinite loop of AJAX requests to the server is happening.

The html `form` sits inside a `div` which has classes 'container mb-4'.  This is the JS code -

```
        var _cont = $('.container.mb-4')
        var _form = $('.custom-form')

        function ajax_validation(form) {

            form.on('change', 'input, select, textarea', function() {

                form_data = form.serialize()

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/form/6/",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: form_data,
                        success: function(data) {
                            if(!(data['success'])) {
                                _cont.empty()
                                _cont.append(data['form_html'])
                                form = _cont.find('form')
                                ajax_validation(form)
                            }
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            form.find('.error-message').show()
                        }
                    });


            })
        }

        ajax_validation(_form)
```

The change event I am assuming is triggered because the server returns a `form` `input` field with a different csrf token as the value to the previous `input` field - all other fields are the same.  So an obvious solution would be to keep the same csrf token.  But I want to understand why the JS code isn't working.  I thought destroying the `form` would destroy the `change` event bound to it.  So am at a loss to explain this infinite loop.  How do I change this so I can just swap the form and not trigger another change event until the user really does change something?

Answer (score 0):

- It's not a good thing to use `events` in `function`  no need to do that
- Also your event here for `input , select , textarea` for serialize you need to select the `closest()` form

Try the next code

```
var _cont = $('.container.mb-4');
var _form = $('.custom-form');

_cont.on('change', 'form input,form select,form textarea', function() {
      var ThisForm = $(this).closest('form');
      var form_data = ThisForm.serialize();
      $.ajax({
        url: "/form/6/",
        type: "POST",
        data: form_data,
        success: function(data) {
           if(!(data['success'])) {
              _cont.html(data['form_html']);
           }
        },
        error: function () {
           ThisForm.find('.error-message').show()
        }
    });
});
```

- And logically `if(!(data['success'])) {` should be `if(data['success']) {`

Answer (score 0):

First let's understand the issue that you have. You have a `function` called `ajax_validation` that is defining a change event on the form's elements which, on response will call `ajax_validation`. So, if any change happens on your elements, then a new request is sent to the server. So, if any value is changed, like a token, the request will be sent again. You could use a semaphore, like this:

```
    var semaphore = true;
    function ajax_validation(form) {

        form.on('change', 'input, select, textarea', function() {

            if (!semaphore) return;
            semaphore = false;
            form_data = form.serialize()

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/form/6/",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: form_data,
                    success: function(data) {
                        if(!(data['success'])) {
                            _cont.empty()
                            _cont.append(data['form_html'])
                            form = _cont.find('form')
                            ajax_validation(form)
                        }
                        semaphore = true;
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        form.find('.error-message').show()
                    }
                });


        })
    }
```

Something like this should solve your issue for the time being, but you should consider refactoring your code, because what you experience is well-known and is called [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the password field was coming back blank from the server - this django must do out of the box if the PasswordInput widget is used.  So the form is replaced with a new form which lacks the password input from the before.  The browser was then applying the autofill password value to the form which was triggering the change event.

This is my code now.  It checks that the form_data about to be sent for validation really is different to before minus the csrf token which will be different.

It is based on Mohamed's answer -

```
        var _cont = $('.container.mb-4');
        var _form = $('.custom-form');

        var prev_data = undefined

        _cont.on('change', 'form input,form select,form textarea', function() {
            var ThisForm = $(this).closest('form');

            var form_data_wo_csrf = ThisForm.find("input, textarea, select").not("input[type='hidden']").serialize()

            if(form_data_wo_csrf == prev_data) {
                return
            }

            var form_data = ThisForm.serialize()

            $.ajax({
                url: "/form/6/",
                type: "POST",
                data: form_data,
                success: function(data) {
                if(!(data['success'])) {
                    _cont.html(data['form_html']);
                    prev_data = form_data_wo_csrf
                }
                },
                error: function () {
                ThisForm.find('.error-message').show()
                }
            });
        });
```